# Хотя бы 1 из 2-ух обязательных checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox

В форме есть 2 checkbox, как отправлять форму ,только если хотя бы один checkbox активен, если оба неактивны - не отправлять?

```
<form>
<div class="checkboxes">
        <ul class="cheke">

          <li>                                                                   
              <input type="checkbox" name="metar" id="metar">
              <label for="metar">METAR/SPECI</label>
          </li>
          <li>
              <input type="checkbox" name="taf" id="taf" >
              <label for="taf">TAF</label>
          </li>                                        

      </ul>    
</div>
<button type="submit" id="send" name="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Где ваш пример?

Comment: @Y.Ghorbani Да думаю тут и без примера понятно, .Ну вот моя форма

Comment: Логическое "или", она же дизъюнкция, Вам о чём-то говорит?

Comment: @eXCore говорит, я просто незнаю как это написать на js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]");

  $("#form").on('submit', function(e) {
    var checker = false;
    checkboxes.each(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
        checker = true;
      }
    });

    if (checker == false) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('не выбран ни один чекбокс, форма не отправлена');
    } else {
      console.log('выбран хотя бы 1 чекбокс, форма отправлена');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="test">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" value="test2">
  <input type="submit" value="отправить">
</form>
```